# how to create an organizational wide lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I worked a few years ago with sharepoint (a local server).
Some concepts where slightly different then.
Now working at another company, where there is an existing sharepoint 365 implementation.
It has a few department sites in it.

And I'd like to generate a few lists that should be available to all department sites.
ea, customer list, project nr, document type list (plan/aquisition/client/order/contract etc).

How and where does one generates company organization wide lists in sharepoint online.
As currently i seam to be only able to save them to a specific site?.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint lists are stored in sites, they do not exist outside of a site. You can however grant access to all of people in the tenant, specific groups or individuals using SharePoint permissions.

For more information on SharePoint permissions, see the articles below:

[SharePoint site permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions)

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

**Edit:** If you need to share content types between multiple sites, you can do this by using the Content Type Gallery. Content types published in the gallery are synced to sites in your SharePoint Online tenant. More information can be found here:

[Publish a content type](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/publish-content-type)

Comment: if i allow everyone on a 'share to all site', then is that list useable as column to other sites?. as if not list scenario's for an organziation / enterprise wide scope becomme impossible and such functionality was available in the past

Comment: I have updated my answer to include information about publishing content types (which include columns). The content type gallery is powered by the content type hub which has long been the way to share content types between multiple sites (site collections). Though subsites can utilise the content types from the parent site.

Comment: If this response answered your question, please do mark it as the answer or upvote the response. This helps ensure that questions and responses are useful to the wider community.

Comment: I will test it in my next work schedule for this, which in about a week from now.